# How to show a page looks like on cellphone, tablets, and desktops without opening a new browser window

Tags: javascript, responsive-design

I am doing a web application which allows users to build pages. In addition to building pages, I will need to show how a page looks like on cellphone, tablet, and desktop without a user actually opening a browser of different viewport sizes to see how it looks.

Here is what I am planning to do a page as follows:

1. The page has two parts.
2. The top part contains three buttons labeled as cellphone, tablet, and desktop
3. The lower part show the actual user page.

Clicking on any of the buttons will show, in the lower part, how a user page looks like on the type of device corresponding to the type represented by a button.

I know that I have to use Javascript for this implementation, but I have no idea where to start.

Any thoughts/links/pointers are really appreciated.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: http://mattkersley.com/responsive/ - load it in an iframe https://github.com/mattkersley/Responsive-Design-Testing

Comment: Christina, this is what I did eventually. If you create an answer, I will select it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome you can emulate any size/screen size by opening developer tools and clicking the phone icon next to the magnifying glass in the top left corner. Here's some docs explaining it https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode

Comment: This is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: the answer you have explained and the question the OP said is entirely dfferent

Comment: Imo, Thanks for your input. I need the capability in my application which will run in different browsers.

Comment: Just re-read your question, maybe you could start with wrapping the user page in a `<div id="content">` and changing the width of the div on each button press? `<button onclick="document.getElementById('content').style.width = '480px'">Mobile View</button>`